# What is an event table (wxWidgets)?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

What exactly is an event table and what does it do? I am asking regarding wxWidgets but maybe its a general GUI programming concept, so please correct me on that.

Comment: You might want to be more specific with your question..

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_events.html#overview_events_eventtables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it simple, the evend table tells which function to call when which event occurrs.

However, it is an old way of mapping events to functions.
It is no longer recommanded because isn't very flexible, and use macro tricks to do its job.
Macros themselves are generally not very recommanded in C++.

Unless you must stick to C++03, you should no longer use event tables.
Instead, you should use the bind method for New WXWidgets projects in C++11 or later.
Bind is more flexible, and don't use macro.

You will find this recommandation in the WXWidgets tutorials, too.
You must still be able to read and understand old event tables, though, because many samples haven't been updated for ages.

Answer (score 0):

An event table tells wxWidgets to map events to member functions. It should be defined in a .cpp file.

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE()
```

is an example of a macro

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: Why doesn't the wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE function need a colon after the statement?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it as such, i.e. with a fresh post. That being said, questions here should be _well researched_ and more than just a few words. You should spend more than a few moments on them.

Comment: Also that's not a function, and I think you mean semi-colon

Comment: Yeah, I assumed he meant semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to say that if you're starting learning wxWidgets, you should know that event tables are a legacy way of handling events and that using [Bind()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind) is the preferred way of doing it in the new code.

In particular, `Bind()` is much less "magic", and doesn't use any macros.